# Where is the code that compute the stealth address

Tags: implementation

A similar question has been asked here [1], but it is still unclear to me so far...

I'm looking for the **specific** part of computing the formula:

> P = Hs(rA)G + B

I've been lost my way while looking at [2] since the structs and the names of the functions are not well clear and documented.

Thanks!

[1]-[Where is the code that generates stealth addresses and matches them with view keys?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8035/where-is-the-code-that-generates-stealth-addresses-and-matches-them-with-view-ke)

[2]-https://github.com/monero-
project/monero/blob/102a51bcd48a3cd2cb794aab7dbe243393f155b3/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp#L197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of that white paper formula is actually `P = Hs(8rA || i)G+B`.

The `8` is there to force the `rA` EC point to be in the group of the base point G, even when `A` is a malicious point which is not in the base point group (i.e. is not a multiple of G).

The `||` symbol means byte concatenation, i.e. concatenate the bytes of the compressed representation of the EC point `8rA` with a varint byte representation of the output index `i`. The output index is appended so that multiple outputs to the same recipient won't have identical public keys (which would be a disaster, because then they'd also share the same key image and only one of them would be able to be spent).

On this line you'll see a call to `generate_key_derivation`: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/102a51bcd48a3cd2cb794aab7dbe243393f155b3/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp#L393

The `generate_key_derivation` method calculates the `8rA` part using `ge_scalarmult` to calculate the `rA` part and using `ge_mul8` to turn that into `8rA`.

On this line you'll see a call to `derive_public_key` https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/102a51bcd48a3cd2cb794aab7dbe243393f155b3/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp#L408

The `derive_public_key` method takes the already calculated `8rA`, uses the `derivation_to_scalar` method (which in turn uses the `hash_to_scalar` method) to produce `Hs(8rA || i)`, and then uses `ge_scalarmult_base` to multiply it by `G` to get `Hs(8rA || i)G`. Finally it adds `B` to get the final result `Hs(8rA || i)G+B`.

You'll see some confusing methods like `ge_p3_to_cached` and `ge_p1p1_to_p2` etc. This is because the most efficient way of performing different operations on EC points is to convert them into different representations prior to particular operations. For more information, see "Faster Addition and Doubling on
Elliptic Curves" https://cr.yp.to/talks/2007.12.03/slides.pdf